# Sencha/PhoneGap App - iOS7 on video close, white space

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, webview

I have been throwing idea around trying to figure out how to fix this thing, but I can't figure it out.

So what we have, we are using the sencha video to display the videos.

```
var video = {
    xtype: 'video',
    url: res,
    posterUrl: shortd[1],
    enableControls: true
};

Ext.getCmp('VideoInfoVideo').add(video);
```

When the video is played, iOS7 opens it in full screen and when closing the video, about 20px of white space is added to the bottom (to the entire app). If you open the video again, another 20px is added.

jQuery see's the difference in the body tag, but when setting the height to the original, it does nothing.

Forgot to mention, Sencha Version: 2.3.1, Phone Gap 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a hacky fix to work around this.

I would detect when the video would end or exit full screen and then have a 200ms delay to reset the height on the app to remove the 20px white space.